# Is it still possible to implement iOS Campaign Tracking using Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I am trying to implement Campaign Tracking using GA on my iOS app, but it turns out that the guide provided by Google to do that is outdated(???) as most of the options required to setup the property in GA are not there anymore. Options such as **Campaign Tracking is On**, **Customization tab**, **Google Analytics Property Id (e.g. UA-XXXX-Y)** are nowhere to be found. Can anyone guide me through to find these options so I can proceed? Is this something that is not supported anymore by GA? Am I looking at an outdated guide?

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S: This is the guide I am using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#troubleshoot-enable

Comment: I believe most of this has been replaced by Firebase Analytics.